# Wordpress column header full image

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I want to achieve this with a column in Wordpress;

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj19Z.png)

A column with a Image header and some text beneath. It will function as a content box.

It is something easy i know, but i cant figure it out right now = (

Help me out please

Comment: Please include your code in a snippet.

Comment: I dont have a code, its in Visual composer. I just have a text block in the column and now i want a image header above it. I did it before but im lost right now.

Comment: https://vc.wpbakery.com/video-academy/visual-composer-tutorial-for-beginners/ from minute 14 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```css
.box {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.box .body {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="" alt="img" />
  <div class="body">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>Body</p>
    <button>A button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```